# Understanding Pytorch filter function

Tags: python, pytorch

I was going through the documentation of PyTorch framework and found lots of instances where a variable is assigned a function but when it calls the function the parameters change. Not sure on how this works, any pointers would be helpful.

What I do understand -

```
def func1(word):
    print("hello", word)
var1 = func1
```

Now in this scenario, `var1("world")` would print the string `hello world`.

But what I dont understand is some lines from PyTorch like:

```
def __init__(self, input_size, num_classes): 
    super(NN,self).__init__()
    self.fc1 = nn.Linear(input_size, 50)  
    self.fc2 = nn.Linear(50, num_classes)  
def forward(self,x):
    x = F.relu(self.fc1(x))
    x = self.fc2(x)
    return x
```

How do we know that only 1 param should be passed to `self.fc2`. It seems to be independent of the number of params defined in `nn.Linear`
Does nn.Linear return a function like func1 that we store in var1 from the earlier example? If so is there any documentation on what is being returned?

I do find the usage for each function in the nn module but is there something that gives more details on how exactly this works?

Comment: First, it seems that you need to ramp up somewhat more on how functions, variables, and classes work.  I suspect that much of your problem is that you need to be more familiar with the basic concepts and terminology.  That would be a personal tutorial, not a Stack Overflow service.

Comment: Yes, `nn.Linear` returns a filter function that accepts an array and returns an array.  This is true for most of the functions in the `torch.nn` module.  The parameters to `Linear` give the size of the arrays, and the documentation shows how the sizes are manipulated.

Comment: Strictly speaking, `Linear` is a class that defines `__call__`, so its instances are callable *like* a function.

Comment: @chepner I went through the implementation of Linear and dont find a __call__, although i did read it up elsewhere and got an idea of how it could possibly work.[link](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/_modules/torch/nn/modules/linear.html#Linear)
I see in the forward function that a call to functional.linear is made which takes in only one input X and produces the output[source](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/nn.functional.html#torch.nn.functional.linear)
What I dont understand yet though is, when is the forward function in Linear called? Is this how inheritence works?

Comment: @Prune I agree that this isnt a question of SoF. Just wasnt able to find the solution to this question anywhere else and I didnt know what to Google even.

Comment: If you agree that it's not a SO question, then please delete it.  Your question is answered by looking at the documentation for `Linear`.  The quantity of parameters to a function is unrelated to its return type.

Comment: @Prune my issue wasnt with the return type. Ofcourse I understand that it has no correlation to the number of params. I'm just not clear on how the forward function of the super class is called implicitly from the subclass when all it does is invoke the constructor. (\__init\__) If someone can clear that part out, i will delete this question ASAP.

Comment: I understand more clearly now.  I've removed my closure and down votes.  Your question involves the source code of the parent's `__init__` method, which you didn't include here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`nn.Linear` is not a function (and neither are all the other layers, like the convolution layers, batchnorms...), but a functor, which means it is a class which implements the `__call__` method/operator which is called when you write something like `self.fc2(x)`.

The `__call__` operator is implemented in the [nn.Module](https://github.com/pytorch/pytorch/blob/master/torch/nn/modules/module.py) base class, and it's a call to another method `_call_impl` which itself calls (basically) the `forward` method. Therefore, thanks to inheritance magic, when you make a class derive from `nn.Module`, you only need to implement the `forward` method.

The signature of this method is kinda up to you, but in most cases it will take a tensor as input and return another tensor.

In summary  :

```
# calls the constructor of nn.Linear. self.fc1 is now a functor
self.fc1 = nn.Linear(20, 10)
# calls the fc1 functor on an input 
y = self.fc1(torch.randn(2, 10))
# which is basically doing
y = self.fc1.forward(torch.randn(2, 10))
```